# Eclipse Workspace Path Error

Tags: java, eclipse, sdk, samsung-smart-tv

I download SDK 4.5 on Samsung webpage. After i add a samsung's example codo. Everything is successfully. But when i execute it being follow Error:
Eclipse Workspace Path Error
- Please don't use spaces.
- Please change Eclipse workspace path

please help me about this.
thanks so much.

Comment: In Eclipse menu go in File option, then on Switch Workspace and create new workspace in other drive.

Comment: Then try to execute your code. Hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use spaces on your workspace path.

If it's on "c:\My long folder with spaces\Name\Workspace for code\Shapur Mohit Magwar\workspace" it won't work.

Try c:\Coding\eclipse_workspace instead.